# Site behaves differently on IE11 after having used it on Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, video-streaming, microsoft-edge

I'm currently in the process of developing a livestreaming website using the [JSMPEG](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) tech. There is multiple streams running simultaneously, and all are rendering to a canvas. The problem I'm experiencing is that the streams render really slow and delayed on IE11, but after launching and running it on edge, and going back to IE11 afterwards, it suddenly works smoothly. I realize this is a bit of a weird behavior but I've tested it multiple times with the same result. Is there any way that having run edge changes the behavior of or enables some acceleration for IE11?

Comment: Will be really hard to help you with such a trivial bug, it could come from anywhere from your code that we have to guess, to your neighbor's cat which could have corrupted your computer. A few things you can try to check by yourself: does this only happen in this way? (i.e does Edge always renders smoothly?) Does this happens only on IE11? (i.e do you experience it on other browsers) Isn't it server side (your server could limit the streaming rate when only one connection is made) What happens hen you open multliple tabs simultaneously on IE11? What was doing your neighbor's cat the 09/28/17?

Comment: I recently saw something similar where we were getting poor performance in IE11, but good once F12 tools were enabled.  Following these steps ( https://superuser.com/a/1179938/156700) I traced the issue to IPSEng32.dll, which then led to the conclusion that a SEP (Symantec) definition update had caused the issue...  Your root cause may differ, but the method of tracing may help you refine your target.

Comment: Edge has a setting for how codecs are installed. Let sites save protected media licenses on my computer..